# I cannot access to amazon ec2(ubuntu) server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, server

I cannot not access to the amazon EC2 instance via ssh. I have the pem file of key pair with same name and same key.

How can I access server? I would like to mention one more thing - in previous day I was able to connect to server, but today it is not working.

Could someone lead me the way I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, problem with SSH connection could has various number of reasons.

1. Your has a wrong key. Even if it has "the same name", your key could be revoked from AWS admin panel
2. Your IP address has changed, or you forgot to connect to VPC/use VPN. AWS provides using different security groups for accessing to their resources. Check your one.
3. You're using a wrong port.

To understand, what is your problem, firstly try to connect with `-vv` option:

```
ssh username@ip:port -i path/to/key.pem -vv
```

And read the output and then you should figure out the way to solve your connection issue.